# Finding one array in another Array

Tags: c

We have two arrays

```
char A[]="ABABABABBBABAB";
```

And the other is

```
char B[]="BABA";
```

How can I find `B` in `A` and where it starts and where it ends for every occurence?

For example for this one

```
Between 2-5
Between 4-7
Between 10-13
```

Comment: Maybe `substr`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this using `strstr` function.

> This function returns a pointer to the first occurrence in haystack of any of the entire sequence of characters specified in needle, or a null pointer if the sequence is not present in haystack.

So you will find the pointer pointing the beginning of the string. But then again if you want to find the next occurence you will change the first parameter accordingly omitting the portion where first occurence is found. A simple illustration :-

```
   char haystack[]="abismyabnameab";
   char needle[]="ab";
   char *ret;
   ret = strstr(haystack, needle);
   while(ret != NULL){
      /* do work */

      printf("%s (%zu,%zu)\n",ret, ret-haystack, ret-haystack+strlen(needle)-1 );
      ret = strstr(haystack+(ret-haystack)+1,needle);
   }
```

I omitted the part where you get those count's where it spits out the indices of the `needle`. As an hint notice one thing - the length of the needle will eb known to you and where it starts you know that using `strstr`. (`ret - haystack` specifically for each instance of `needle` in `haystack`).

Note this illustration code is showing the example for strings which are non-recurring within itself. For example, `BB` is found in `BBBBB` then we will find every occurrence in each position. But the solution above skips the second occurrence.  A simple modification is adding to `haystack` `1` to search in string one character later than the previous iteration.

Better solution is to find the failure function using KMP. That will give a better complexity solution. `O(n+m)`. But in earlier case it is `O(n*m)`.